# How to Interpret roc_curve(Test,Predictions) in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining

I am working with scikit-learn for classification problem to predict Win or Loss of an opportunity.
 I used the piece of code:

```
fpr, tpr, thresholds =roc_curve(yTest,predictions)
```

And the result is:

```
    (array([ 0.       ,  0.2628946,  1.       ]),
     array([ 0.        ,  0.73692477,  1.        ]),
     array([2, 1, 0]))
```

I am aware of calculating the AUC using the fpr, tpr for various thresholds varying in the range (1,0). Ideally, what I know is thresold should be in between 1 and 0.

But, here the threshold values are 2,1,0. What to understand from this and how to interpret this.

The sample code looks fine:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
scores = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y, scores, pos_label=2)
>>>fpr
array([ 0. ,  0.5,  0.5,  1. ])
>>>tpr
array([ 0.5,  0.5,  1. ,  1. ])
>>> thresholds
array([ 0.8 ,  0.4 ,  0.35,  0.1 ])
```

My predict_proba(yTest) are:

```
[ 0.09573287  0.90426713]
 [ 0.14987409  0.85012591]
 [ 0.16348188  0.83651812]
 ..., 
 [ 0.13957409  0.86042591]
 [ 0.04478675  0.95521325]
 [ 0.03492729  0.96507271]
```

Comment: Can you share the values in your yTest and predictions arrays?

Comment: @AbhinavArora : Edited my Question

Answer (score 0):

Thresholds are not confined to [0;1].

Only TPR and FPR are rates, i.e. 0 to 1.

If you see the **documentation**, it will tell you how it arrived at the value 2:

> Decreasing thresholds on the decision function used to compute fpr and tpr. `thresholds[0]` represents no instances being predicted and is arbitrarily set to `max(y_score) + 1`.

If your input data has the values `[100,42,42,3.14]`, then it will consider the thresholds `[101, 100, 42, 3.14]`.

Judging from your thresholds being `[2,1,0]`, you are *not* using this function the right way. You probably have switched the two parameters? Because the output indicates that your input scores are all either 0, or 1. On such data, the ROC curve degenerates, and you simply use precision and recall. But if you have switched the scores and the labels, you may get a real ROC curve.